# Setting the proper root / redirect path for nginx website in subfolder

Tags: nginx, multisite

I have 2 websites that can be both accessed at the same URL, only one is accessible from a subfolder like this:

website.com/

website.com/blog

Now they are running under Apache and I want to switch to Nginx and I stumbled upon the rewriting rules of Nginx in this approach.

The hosting server is an Ubuntu with Plesk so the only part I need to edit is the one that is responsible for the rewrites based on the URL format.

The original starting point is this one:

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    set $test P;
}
if ($uri !~ ^/(plesk-stat|webstat|webstat-ssl|ftpstat|anon_ftpstat|awstats-icon|internal-nginx-static-location)) {
    set $test "${test}C";
}
if ($test = PC ) {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?$1;
}
```

This works great for the main website, however, the one located in *blog* will show the homepage but any other inner page will return a 404 error.

So the first approach I had towards this was this one:

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    set $test P;
}
if ($uri !~ ^/(plesk-stat|webstat|webstat-ssl|ftpstat|anon_ftpstat|awstats-icon|internal-nginx-static-location)) {
    set $test "${test}C";
}
if ($uri ~ ^/(*blog*)) {
    set $test "B";
}
if ($test = PC ) {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?$1;
}
if ($test = B ) {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /blog/index.php?$1;
}
```

But this does not work so I tried an approach based on location like this:

```
location  / {

if (!-e $request_filename) {
    set $test P;
}
if ($uri !~ ^/(plesk-stat|webstat|webstat-ssl|ftpstat|anon_ftpstat|awstats-icon|internal-nginx-static-location)) {
    set $test "${test}C";
}
if ($test = PC ) {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?$1;
}

}


location ~ /blog {

root httpdocs/blog

if (!-e $request_filename) {
    set $test P;
}
if ($uri !~ ^/(plesk-stat|webstat|webstat-ssl|ftpstat|anon_ftpstat|awstats-icon|internal-nginx-static-location)) {
    set $test "${test}C";
}
if ($test = PC ) {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?$1;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with the current configuration:

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    set $test P;
}
if ($uri !~ ^/(plesk-stat|webstat|webstat-ssl|ftpstat|anon_ftpstat|awstats-icon|internal-nginx-static-location|blog)) {
    set $test "${test}C";
}
if ($uri ~ ^/(blog)) {
    set $test "${test}B";
}
if ($test = PC ) {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?$1;
}
if ($test = PB ) {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /blog/index.php?$1;
}
```